# Using BIRT, how can I ensure that the background colour in a row is the same height in each cell in the row?

Tags: formatting, birt

I have a BIRT report that I have set up to use conditional formatting so that the colour of the row alternates between grey and white. It works as expected except for the fact that the grey colour in a field with a string extends slightly below where the grey extends in a field with an integer. In other words, if the grey background is 1 inch high with an integer, it is 1.1 inch high with a string. I cannot see any differences in any of the margin or padding settings so I am not sure what would be causing this small issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to be confused with styling, because we can set style properties on rows, cells or data fields within cells. 
As you describe this issue, i think you have not applied this conditional formatting on rows, but on cells or data fields.

When a BIRT table is selected in the outline view of Eclipse designer, we need to click on the left to select the whole row, and then define a conditional formatting. Thus, physically we can't have height differences between cells (at least in html format) because the style is applied on a "div" container.